# $A$ is hermitian if and only if $\langle A\alpha,\beta\rangle= \langle\alpha ,A\beta\rangle$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can i prove that $A$ is hermitian if and only if $\langle A\alpha,\beta\rangle= \langle\alpha ,A\beta\rangle$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{C}^n$

i stuck in this problem i know that if $A$ is hermitian then it is self-adjoint but how can i prove this, some help please

Comment: What is the definition of self-adjoint?

Comment: $A$ is self-adjoint if and only if $ A = A^*$

Comment: What is the definition of $A^*$? (I promise I have a purpose with these questions)

Comment: $<Ax ,y>= <x ,A^*y>$

Comment: @Knight Correction: $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle$. This is the definition of an adjoint.

Comment: So if by supposition we have $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,Ay\rangle$ and we also have by definition that $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle$, what do you expect the relationship to be between $A$ and $A^*$?

Comment: Can you argue why? (It seems obvious but you need just a little bit of work to see it.)

Comment: i know that $A$ is hermitian if $A = A^t$ conjugate is that correct ? for complexes

Comment: i have a question for this is equivalent to prove this that "A is a Hermitian projection if and only if it is an orthogonal projection" ?¿

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The complex inner product $\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle$ is defined as $$
\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle = \mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{y}$$ where $\mathbf{x}^H$ denotes Hermitian conjugate. Write out the expressions for $\langle \alpha, A \beta\rangle$ and $\langle A\alpha,\beta\rangle$ and see what you get.

Results:

> $\langle \alpha, A \beta\rangle = \alpha^HA\beta = \alpha^HA^H\beta = (A\alpha)^H\beta = \langle A\alpha,\beta\rangle$

This proves the forward direction. The reverse follows from the definition of Hermitian adjoint.